# Application for blackberry 6,7,10

Tags: blackberry

I have a project. This application should run on blackberry 6,7 and 10. I have downloaded blackberry 7.0.1 plugins for Eclipse. When I compile a few times it showed no error in the console and it showed the application icon on blackberry simulator but this application is not running. May I know the files I should add or relevant changes I should make in the project to run it?

While I was surfing I come to know same source code cannot be used for blackberry 6 ,7 and blackberry 10.
Only Android run on blackberry 10.

The worst part about the project is, it is developed by client and we are not aware on which platform it is developed and the code is very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

To develop applications for RIM OS 6.x and 7.x you need Eclipse with relevant plugin versions installed (6.x and 7.x). Applications compiled with SDK 6.x may run on RIM OS 7.x but it won't provide the best user experience. Use preprocessor to compile separate set of .cod files for separate device OS version using one source file set.

BB 10 - has nothing in common with RIM OS 6.x/7.x and apps compiled for RIM OS 6.x/7.x won't run on BB 10 and vice versa. BB 10 is not compatible with previous BB RIM OS. It is completely new platform and needs separate SDK (for C++ language).

The one exception is when you are not writing a native application, and you are making a WebWorks/PhoneGap application. But as far as I understand from your question your project is a native application.

Comment: In my project their is one package imported,this package is developed on java ground platform.Their are few more folders like rpgenerator nbproject,bin,resource,source,temparory,build,build.xml,build.bat folders Is their any way out to understand the code each and every bit and make it execuatble.

Comment: It is a BB native app, written on java using [Netbeans IDE](http://www.netbeans.org). It is not an Eclipse project. If you want to use Eclipse, then make a new project and transfer source, libraries (if any) code and resources to this new empty project. Also you will need to check original ant-build scripts/preprocessor directives to fine tune your eclipse project and make it working.

Comment: may you help me ,selecting which  versions of jdk ,jde ,jre ,sdk and service pack for blackberry 6,7 and 10 platform please hope i am not troubling you lot

Comment: To get information for BB 10 development check [this link](https://developer.blackberry.com/platforms/ndk). To get information for RIM OS 6/7 native apps development check [this link](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/). Also there is an [official developer support forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Developer-Support-Forums/ct-p/blackberrydev).

Comment: do i need to study ant-build scripts/preprocessor directives, or is their any smarter way to accomplish the task without studying.hey you have very sound knowledge and aware of many things which i dont even know,even i wish to know all this and help people here.thanks lot Rafael

Comment: Here is the link to [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) documentation. It is a simple thing, which allows to automate routine build tasks. Study it before working with your ant script files. [Preprocessing is a thing for conditional compilation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Specifying_preprocessor_directives_657636_11.jsp). You just add special directives directly to your source code, and according to these directives compilator compiles or skips parts of your source code. It allows you to make different cod-builds from one source files set.

Comment: Also check [this link](http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/11/coding-for-multiple-blackberry-devices.html)

Comment: while running my project this(microsoft visual c++ runtime library r6002 floating point  support not loaded) error message is coming . the solution i got is ,their is some registry problem and i need to do antivirus scan, but it is not helpful.may you help me.the above link are very much helpful thanks may i know how and from where you got this link